# JQuery multiply input values of table rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, jquery-selectors

I want to calculate each row's total price by multiplying individual row's inputs and then finally calculate a grand total by adding all the total values of the Total column using JQuery. I am only getting the first row to display total when I enter values. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
     <script type="text/C#" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".txtMult").each(function () {
                $(this).keyup(function () {
                    multInputs();
                });
            });
           });

           function multInputs() {
               var mult = 0;
               $(".txtMult").each(function () {
                   var $val1 = $('#val1').val();
                   var $val2 = $('#val2').val();
                   var $total = ($val1 * 1) * ($val2 * 1)
                   $('#multTotal').text($total);
               });
           }

    </script>
    @using (@Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Quanity
            </th>
            <th>
                Unit Price
            </th>
            <th>
                Total
            </th>
        </tr>
        @for (int i=0; i < 5; i++)
        {

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input class ="txtMult" name="txtEmmail" id="val1"  />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class ="txtMult" name="txtEmmail" id="val2"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span id="multTotal">0.00</span>
                </td>
            </tr>

    }
<tr>
    <td colspan="3" align="right">
        Grand Total# <span id="grandTotal">0.00</span>
    </td>
</tr>
    </table> 
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your html is invalid: the `id` attribute is supposed to be unique but you are repeating the same three ids in every row. The easiest way to fix this is to change your inputs to have `class="val1"` and `class="val2"` instead of `id="val1"` and `` `id="val2" ``, and change your row total to have `class="multTotal"`. I'd also move the `txtMult` class to each of the tr elements with the inputs in them, for ease of selecting those rows:

```
        <tr class="txtMult">
            <td>
                <input name="txtEmmail" class="val1"  />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="txtEmmail" class="val2"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span class="multTotal">0.00</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

...and then change the selector in your jQuery code to select by class *in the context of the current row*. Note also that you don't need an `.each()` loop to bind the `.keyup()` handlers to the elements that match your selector, just use `$("someselector").keyup()`:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
       $(".txtMult input").keyup(multInputs);

       function multInputs() {
           var mult = 0;
           // for each row:
           $("tr.txtMult").each(function () {
               // get the values from this row:
               var $val1 = $('.val1', this).val();
               var $val2 = $('.val2', this).val();
               var $total = ($val1 * 1) * ($val2 * 1);
               // set total for the row
               $('.multTotal', this).text($total);
               mult += $total;
           });
           $("#grandTotal").text(mult);
       }
  });
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nnnnnn/5FpWC/

Comment: I think I can't use two class on a same input <input class ="txtMult" name="txtEmmail" class="val1"  /> What would be the best way to fix this?

Comment: You _can_ use two or more classes on the same element, just separate the class names with spaces within a single `class` attribute: `<input class="txtMult val1 otherclass etc" name="txtEmmail">`. Note though that in my solution I removed the `txtMult` class from the inputs and put it on the tr elements (you could still target the inputs in your stylesheet by using a selector of `tr.txtMult input` - which says 'select any inputs that are descendants of tr elements with "txtMult" class').

Answer (score 1):

Let add a class `in` to the table.

At first add a change event to all inputs of the table. On change of a input field multiply all inputs of same row and update the `multTotal` and `grandTotal`

```
$(function(){
            $('.in input').change(function(){
                var p=$(this).parent().parent() //get the parent of changed input
                var m=p.find('input.txtMult') //find all input of the row
                var mul=parseFloat($(m[0]).val()*$(m[1]).val()).toFixed(2) //multiply them
                var res=p.find('.multTotal') // get corresponding multTotal
                res.html(mul); //show the result
                var total=0;
                $('.in .multTotal').each(function(){
                    total+=parseFloat($(this).html())
                }) //calculate grand total
                $('.in #grandTotal').html(parseFloat(total).toFixed(2)) //show grand total
            });
        })
```

check this at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sarowar/Hvsu7/)

If need to process more than 2 fields change

```
var mul=parseFloat($(m[0]).val()*$(m[1]).val()).toFixed(2) //multiply them
```

to

```
var mul=1;
$(m).each(function(){
  mul*=$(this).val()
})
mul=parseFloat(mul).toFixed(2)
```

Comment: Note that you don't need `parseFloat()` for things that are already numbers, i.e., you don't need to use it on your `total` variable and you don't need to use it on `$(m[0]).val()*$(m[1]).val()` because the `*` operator converts both operands to numbers.

Comment: you are right about total. but `$(m[0]).val()*$(m[1]).val()` is parsed to show the result up to two decimal point when given input is integer.