# Adding, Subtracting and Multiplying form input values

Tags: jquery, forms, input

Based on this post from here, [JQuery multiply input values of table rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11789683/jquery-multiply-input-values-of-table-rows), i used the same form field names and added Tax field and Discount field.

```
        <tr class="txtMult">
        <td>
            <input name="txtEmmail" class="val1"  />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="txtEmmail" class="val2"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span class="multTotal">0.00</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
        <tr class="txtMult">
        <td>
            <input name="txttax" class="val1"  />%
        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td>
            <span class="multTax">0.00</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

This tax needs to be multiplied, like if i enter 10 (%)

```
var $tax = ($val1 * 1) * ($total * 1)/100;
$('.multTax', this).text($tax);
```

and then out put that as a tax amount 
I changed the txttax class value as val3 and added the jquery like above

again, I need to subtract the discount, I tried all possible ways, but no luck.

this is the function (Edited)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(".txtMult input").keyup(multInputs);
   function multInputs() {
       var mult = 0;
       $("tr.txtMult").each(function () {
           var $val1 = $('.val1', this).val();
           var $val2 = $('.val2', this).val();
           var $val3 = $('.val3', this).val();
           var $total = ($val1 * 1) * ($val2 * 1);
           var $tax = ($val1 * 1) * ($total * 1)/100;
           $('.multTotal', this).text($total);
           $('.multTax', this).text($tax);
           mult += $total;
       });
       $("#grandTotal").text(mult);
   }
});
```

Please advise. (spent the whole day)

Comment: Where are `$val1`, `$total`, and `$tax` defined?

Comment: @Andrew Whitaker, edited again :)

Comment: @sammry Please remove unrelated markup; it serves only to obfuscate. Only the form fields and spans matter. Keep questions focused only on relevant issues. Note that you have two fields with class `.val1`, two inputs named `txtEmmail`, and none named `.val3`, is this intentional? It seems odd and counter to your code.

Comment: @DaveNewton what exactly should i remove? am sorry, bit confused.

Comment: @DaveNewton yes, i used .val3 to multiply the $total and also tried as .val1, but no luck

Comment: @sammry The unrelated markup. Only the inputs and spans matter. There's no `.val3` element I can see; using it in the JS makes little sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**jsFiddle solution**](http://jsfiddle.net/KCjHb/1/)

HTML

```
 <table>
 <tr class="txtMult">
    <td>
        <input name="txtEmmail" class="val1"  />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name="txtEmmail" class="val2"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <span class="multTotal">0.00</span>
    </td>
</tr>
    <tr class="txtMult odd">
    <td>
        <input name="txttax" class="val3"  />%
    </td>
    <td>

    </td>
    <td>
        <span class="multTax">0.00</span>
    </td>
 </tr>
 </table>

 <span id="grandTotal"></span>
```

JS

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

   $("input").keyup(multInputs);
   function multInputs() {
       var mult = 0;
       $("tr.txtMult").not('.odd').each(function () {           
           var $val1 = $('.val1', this).val();
           var $val2 = $('.val2', this).val();
           var $val3 = $('.val3', $(this).next()).val();

           var $total = $val1 * $val2;
           var $tax = $val3 * ($total / 100);

           $('.multTotal', this).text($total);
           $('.multTax', $(this).next()).text($tax);

           mult += $total - $tax;
       });

       $("#grandTotal").text(mult);
   }
});
```

Comment: hi @ozerich , thanks for the answer, tax amount is not right. for val1=50 and val2=50 total is 5000, when i enter txttax=10 (%), the answer is not right, am playing with the multiplier now. Thanks

Comment: thank you so much @ozerich, i should follow the same for discount too as val4 with odd tr class