# Multiply and add 2 inputs jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm feeling a little stupid but I can't get this to work. I want to multiply two inputs and then add all totals to get the grand total but it doesn't work and I can't figure out why. I've been looking at several subjects on the subject like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11789683/jquery-multiply-input-values-of-table-rows) but I can't see what I am doing wrong.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.qtyorder').on("keyup change",function(){
        update_amounts();
    });
});

function update_amounts(){
    var sum = 0.00;
    $('#ordertable > tbody  > tr').each(function(){
        var price = $(this).find('.unitprice').val();
        var qty = $(this).find('.qtyorder').val();
        var amount = (qty * price)
        sum+=amount;
        $(this).find('.subtotal').text('' + amount);
    });
    $('.ordertotal').text(sum);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="order-table" id="ordertable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="order-name"></th>
            <th class="order-price">Prix</th>
            <th class="order-qtytotal">Qty</th>
            <th class="order-total">Total</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="order-name"><h2>Product1</h2></td>
            <td class="order-price">
                <input type="text" name="unitprice" class="unitprice" value="30" readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1">
            </td>
            <td class="order-qtytotal">
                <input type="number" class="qtyorder" name="qtyorder" min="0">
            </td>
            <td class="order-total">
                <input type="text" class="subtotal" name="subtotal" readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1" value="0.00">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="order-name"><h2>Product2</h2></td>
            <td class="order-price">
                <input type="text" name="unitprice" class="unitprice" value="40" readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1">
            </td>
            <td class="order-qtytotal">
                <input type="number" class="qtyorder" name="qtyorder" min="0">
            </td>
            <td class="order-total">
                <input type="text" class="subtotal" name="subtotal" readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1" value="0.00">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div class="sommeorder">
    <label for="ordertotal">Total</label>
    <input type="text" class="ordertotal" name="ordertotal" readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1" value="0.00">
</div>
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Are you getting errors?

Comment: You might need to surround `qty` and `price` with `parseFloat()`. As in `var amount = (parseFloat(qty) * parseFloat(price))`

Comment: I have no errors, it just doesn't display anything in the `subtotal` and `ordetotal` input...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things.

Firstly, you're working with `<input>` tags, so you can use `val()` instead of `text()`.  That will get your values to show up.

```
$(this).find('.subtotal').val(amount);
```

---

Secondly, in order for you to be sure that you're getting numbers instead of strings, you can wrap the values in `parseFloat()`.  This will allow you to work with numbers.

```
var price = parseFloat($(this).find('.unitprice').val());
var qty = parseFloat($(this).find('.qtyorder').val());
```

---

Thirdly, for some reason, `sum += amount` wasn't adding correctly.  If you change it to `sum = sum + amount`, it will work.

Here's what it would look like when it works:

```
function update_amounts(){
    var sum = 0.0;
    $('#ordertable > tbody  > tr').each(function(){
        var price = parseFloat($(this).find('.unitprice').val());
        var qty = parseFloat($(this).find('.qtyorder').val());
        var amount = (qty * price)

        if (amount > 0) {
            $(this).find('.subtotal').val(amount);
            sum = sum + amount;
        } else {
            $(this).find('.subtotal').val("0.00");
        }
    });

    if (sum > 0) $('.ordertotal').val(sum);
    else $('.ordertotal').val("0.00");
}
```

[Here's a JSFiddle of it working.](http://jsfiddle.net/5kg6xoL7/)